# How to extract news article headlines based on dates using selenium python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am scraping The URLs of headlines and their dates from [here](https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/tag/rum/)
So this gives me all URls and their which are present on the page. The dates on the respective urls ie the day their published are like June 24th 2021, June 21st 2021 and so on.
I would like to scrape only those URLs which are published 6days before from today's date.
ie if the webpage has 20URLs of the headlines which are published on dates, I want to scrape only those websites which are published from 4th August 2021 till today.
So in my output there will only be dates from 4th August onwards uptil today.

Here's my code of extracting all URL headlines and their dates from the website

```
    websites = ['https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/tag/rum/']
    for spirits in websites:
        browser.get(spirits)
        time.sleep(1)

        news_links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="archivewrapper"]/div/div[2]/h3')
        n_links = [ele.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href') for ele in news_links]
        dates = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="archivewrapper"]/div/div[2]/small')
        n_dates = [ele.text for ele in dates]
        print(n_links)
        print(n_dates)
```

How can I do this? Please help me! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first collect all the links irrespective of the dates and then group them. Below code does the same.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/category/news/")
news = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='archivewrapper']")
newsdata = {}
for ne in news:
    datechk = ne.find_element_by_tag_name("small").get_attribute("innerText").replace(' ','')
    link = ne.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='archivewrapper']//h3/a").get_attribute("href")
    if datechk in newsdata:
        newsdata[datechk].append(link)
    else:
        newsdata[datechk] = [link]
dates = "August{}th,2021"
for i in range(4,12):
    if dates.format(i) in newsdata:
        print(("{} : {}".format(dates.format(i),newsdata[dates.format(i)])))
driver.quit()
```

And the output:

```
August4th,2021 : ['https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/2021/08/cannabis-drinks-market-to-reach-us6bn-by-2031/', 'https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/2021/08/cannabis-drinks-market-to-reach-us6bn-by-2031/', 'https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/2021/08/cannabis-drinks-market-to-reach-us6bn-by-2031/']
August6th,2021 : ['https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/2021/08/cannabis-drinks-market-to-reach-us6bn-by-2031/', 'https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/2021/08/cannabis-drinks-market-to-reach-us6bn-by-2031/']
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your immediate response, I would like to know a few things: You've mentioned dates = August {}th 2021 What if I run the the program at the beginning of the month? or in the next month? The same code if I run on a different url(which i have shared) doesn't work, but using the same code(which I have) I have multiple websites and the xpaths are matching for all.

Comment: @technophile_3- Regarding date: Answer was just a sample. You need to extract the date and optimize in such a way that it matches the date specified in website.

Comment: @technophile_3 - Regarding multiple websites: Are you trying to go next pages in same tag `rum` or you are trying to choose different tag like `gin`  or `vodka` ?

Comment: I am trying to choose all tags basically- gin,vodka, rum, whiskey..

Comment: for tags like these 'gin, vodka, whiskey' the script runs but doesn't give an output, neither an error.

Comment: I figured out..each categories doesn't have entries in August because of which it was not giving an error or the output, I changed the month and it gave me the result...one last thing...What exactly is going on in the for loop..range(4,12)? what exactly is that?

Comment: @technophile_3 - `newsdata` is a dictionary. The dates will be updated to the value of `i`.  The `if statement` checks whether `August4th,2021` is in the dictionary, if it is it prints the `August4th,2021` the key and the value of that key(links).

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the dates are always in the same format(for example like this `Jun 21 2021`)

You can use datetime module's `strfpime()` function

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

my_date = "Jun 21 2021"
my_format = "%b %d %Y"

print(datetime.strptime(my_date, my_format))
```

later u can do whatever you want with the datetime object the funtion returns(like compare the dates)

References:

Doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Formating chart: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: this gives me a value error!-  time data 'June 21 2021' does not match format '%b %d %Y'

Comment: ya sorry for late response i have the link about the formatting chart all the codes you may find one that you need. the above code formats for dates like `jan, feb, mar, ...` then use the code should work but if the month is like `january, febraury, march,...` then use this format instead `'%B %d %Y'`

Comment: yep..checked it. Thanks

Comment: @technophile_3 and make sure you remove the st in **1st** or nd in **2nd** from the string through slicing